# Using A Two Dimensional Array To Tell Where A Player Is In A Text Game

Tags: python, arrays, text

I am trying to make a game in python that is similar to Zork, and I got one working using else if statements, but to make a functional game that would take forever. so I am wondering how I could make this using an array. here is my code:

```
answer_yes = ["Yes", "Y", "yes", "y"]
answer_no = ["No", "N", "no", "n"]
'''
command_north["north"]
command_south["south"]
command_east["east"]
command_west["west"]
command_up["up"]
command_down["down"]
command_attack["attack","fight","kill"]
command_take["take","grab","bring"]
'''

print("""
WELCOME! LET'S START THE ADVENTURE

You are standing outside of your house and a man runs at you Demanding to let him inside

Do you let him in. (Yes / No)
""")

ans1 = input(">>")

if ans1 in answer_yes:
    print("\nAfter 2 minutes, the Police came to your house, and ask you that whether the thief is in your house or not. Will you say (Yes / No)\n")

    ans2 = input(">>")

    if ans2 in answer_yes:
        print("\nYou are an honest person. He was a thief & You won the Game")

    elif ans2 in answer_no:
        print("\nYou helped a thief. Now, go to Jail. GAME OVER")

    else:
        print("\nYou typed the wrong input. GOODBYE!")

elif ans1 in answer_no:
    print("\nNow, he is trying to kill you. Will, you knock him down? (Yes / No)\n")

    ans3 = input(">>")

    if ans3 in answer_yes:
        print("\nCongrats! He was a thief & You helped the police to catch him with your bravery.")

    elif ans3 in answer_no:
        print("\nSorry! You are dead. He was a thief & He killed you. GAME OVER")

    else:
        print("\nYou typed the wrong input. GOODBYE!")

else:
    print("\nYou typed the wrong input. GOODBYE!")
```

So I need the array that can store information as to where the player is, such as in the house or on the street, and than that data can be accessed to tell the user where he is and so the game can be "open world" and the player can move around freely. If you can help please do. I cannot find almost anything on the internet that is what I need. I thought that something like this might work, but I don't know how to represent it in the game:

```
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  2.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

One is a wall, two is something like food to pick up, and zero is empty space.

Comment: If you think about each element in the array as a "location" (which encodes the content/status of that location), then using an array sort of implies that every location has  four (or eight) neighboring locations.   It may be preferable to use a graph structure where each node is a location, edges indicate neighboring locations, and the nodes carry content/status information.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean @Mark Lavin. Could you show me some code?

Comment: Let's call the information you want to represent the "PlayState"; what are
its methods?  (1) What is current location (location player is in), (2) What other locations can be reached from current location, and (3) What objects (e.g., "little axe", "tasty food") are available in the current location?  Then, could you implement PlayState with a Python (numpy) array?  Probably yes, although it slightly restricts the game.  Try sketching the code for the three methods.